# Can I force a state update using a class as a value?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm interested in whether I can update the state forcibly or update the value even if it is equivalent to the previous one. I understand that in my `setState()` it does not work because even after calling `updateAttributes()` ipLocation is not considered a new value, only the information about the latitude and longitude inside was updated. Can I work around this?

```
// Here the `ipLocation` does not contain data on longitude and latitude.
const [ipLocation, setIpLocation] = React.useState<IpLocation>(new IpLocation());

React.useEffect(() => {
    // [GET] request to the server. The server returns a value for the latitude and longitude.
    ipLocation.load()
        .then((response) => {
            // Updating the attributes of the ipLocation, the response has all the data.
            // updateAttributes() method return `this`
            setIpLocation(ipLocation.updateAttributes(response.data.data));
        });
}, []);

return(
    <p>{ipLocation.getAttribute('latitude')}</p>
    <p>{ipLocation.getAttribute('longitude')}</p>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way state is intended to work, as it should be immmutable: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

If you want to keep working with a class you could modify your code so that `updateAttributes` returns a `new IpLocation()`

But why should this be a class as you could simply store an object?

```js
const [ipLocation, setIpLocation] = React.useState<IpLocation>({lat: 0, lng: 0});

React.useEffect(() => {
    // [GET] request to the server. The server returns a value for the latitude and longitude.
    ipLocation.load()
        .then((response) => {
            // Updating the attributes of the ipLocation, the response has all the data.
            // assuming response.data.data contains an object like: { lat: 21.2323344334,lng:24.13243533}
            setIpLocation({...response.data.data}));
        });
}, []);

return(
    <p>{ipLocation.lat}</p>
    <p>{ipLocation.lng}</p>
);
```

Comment: Using a class seems to me more convenient when there are a lot of fields.
You don't need to store a large data object in one file, and you can put it in a separate class.
`React.useState<IpLocation>({lat: 0, lng: 0, ...Many many other fields})` vs `React.useState<IpLocation>(new IpLocation())`

Comment: You can store the object in a separate file aswel and import it for the "default" empty state. And updating any field is as simple and cloning the object and the setting the new updated fields.

```
import YOUR_DEFAULT_OBJECT from '../some/file/path';

function YourComponent() {

  const [ipLocation, setIpLocation] = React.useState<IpLocation>({...YOUR_DEFAULT_OBJECT});

 useEffect( () => {
     const response = await fetch(  ... );
     setIpLocation({...ipLocation, lat: response.data.lat, lng: response.data.lng }));
} )


}

```